# Purpose of 'Boost clamp functionality' in this buck converter

Tags: circuit-design, buck, datasheet

Going over this buck regulator: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp3011-d.pdf

[image]

To break the question in 2 parts:

1. I am not sure I fully understand what the purpose of it is?

I need a supply at 24V and output at 5V, so I don't expect to have a high dutycylce and thereby end up in region3 but would still like to understand how to design for it if that was the case.

2. How would you go about the capacitor optimisation?

Comment: It just sounds like the your typical high-side gate drive using a bootstrap capacitor to me. The "clamp" part is just  a way to regulate the bootstrap cap voltage so it doesn't get too high and blow the gate.

Comment: `I am not sure I fully understand what the purpose of it is` Do you partially understand what it is for?

Comment: Hehe. Guilty. I understand usually a high side Fet (as in motor drives) have a bootstrap capacitor to ensure the gate voltage is higher than the source voltage which is floating when it's open. I just don't seem to follow here when they say it is used to supply high and low side gate driver voltage. That doesn't sound like a boostrap cap to me.

Comment: It doesn't supply the low side MOSFET - where does it say it does?

Comment: 'The boost circuit requires an external capacitor connected
between the BST and VSW pins to store charge for supplying
the high and low−side gate driver voltage'

Comment: @Hasman404 There's no reason it couldn't. The cap is being floated up and down after all. No reason you could not extract charge both times.